# Некорректный переход на страницу

Tags: php, actionscript

Здравствуйте. Итак есть 2 страницы: первая - index, вторая страница с  содержимым сайта, где страницы подключаются с помощью include. На странице index меню на флеше, переходит на другую страницу, только если набирать

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("content.php/?act=kontakti"));
```

соответственно на второй странице сайта я прописываю на PHP ссылку на эту же страницу как:

```
a href="content.php/&act=kontakt"
```

При этом получается, что все работает, но если переключаться на разные страницы сайта в адресной строке, получается

```
www.sait/content.php/content.php/content.php/?act=kontakt
```

Что подскажете?

Comment: Код в студию :)

Comment: php или actionScript, или все вместе?

Answer (score 1):

Слэш в начале или полный путь указывайте. Ссылка "content.php/?act=kontakti" означает "CURRENT_URL/content.php/?act=kontakti".

```
<a href="/content.php?act=kontakti">link</a> или
<a href="http://www.site.com/content.php?act=kontakti">link</a>

navigateToURL(new URLRequest("/content.php?act=kontakti")); или
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.site.com/content.php?act=kontakti"));
```